# Grep and cut the selected field

Tags: text-processing, grep, cut

I am trying to cut the field if a line starts with a particular name,

```
cat $1|while read line
do
if [ "$1" = "custbills.cmp" ]; then
acc_no=`grep "^Custbills" $1 | cut -c29-43`
acc_type=`grep "^Custbills" $1 |cut -c124-125`
echo "\"${acc_no}\",\"${acc_type}\"" >> out.csv
else 
echo ""
fi
done
```

but is giving error and in output file i am getting only ','. 
what is wrong in my script

Comment: have you tried echo${acc_no},${acc_type} ? (without quotes)

Comment: @Archemar i have tried all possible ways and posted here. And keep trying luckily it's worked with below answer so i have posted this answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the script and i got the result

```
if [ "$1" = "custbills.cmp" ]; then
grep "^Custbills" $1 |while read line
do
acc_no=`echo "$line" | cut -c29-43`
acc_type=`echo "$line" |cut -c124-125`
echo "$acc_no","$acc_type" >> out.csv
done
else
echo ""
fi
```

Comment: the you should give you credit for you answer !

Comment: @Archemar the OP [has to wait 48 hours](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) before accepting their own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
if [ "$1" = "custbills.cmp" ]
then
        grep "^Custbills" $1 | cut -c29-43,124-125 --output-delimiter="," >> out.csv
else
        echo ""
fi
```

seems to do exactly the same as the code in your answer.
But you haven’t explained the context of why you’re testing `"$1"`.
Why not just say

```
grep "^Custbills" "custbills.cmp" | cut -c29-43,124-125 --output-delimiter="," > out.csv
```

?

Comment: Your snippet won't have exactly the same output I think; the one in the question will end up with two comma-seperated fields, while yours will have... a lot more than that.